# Creating multiple image SRC element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Image links from the database are registered this way:

```
Here are sample apartment pictures {img="/path/photo1.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"} and {img="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title #2"}
```

While printing on the screen:

```
Here are sample apartment pictures <img src="/path/photo.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"/> and <img src="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title #2"/>
```

How is this changed with JavaScript?

I have studied many questions about this, but I have not found it.

Comment: Do you want to change the source attribute of an existing img element on the page, or do you want to insert a new img element on the page with the data from the database?

Comment: @CamilleSébastienNiessen I want the image to be displayed on the page, I do not want to intervene in the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In jquery you can write it like this:

first of all let's call the img object from the DB by naming it 'imgObj' for the example...
Then:

```js
var imgObj = { img : 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', alt : 'alternative text' };

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img').attr('src', imgObj.img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="#" alt="" class='img' />
```

**UPDATE:** (For couple images)

Now i building the html as string (using the img object from the db) before i append it to the DOM.
For instance:

```js
var imgObj = 
[{ img : 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', alt : 'alternative text', class:'img-1' },
 { img : 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', alt : 'alternative text', class:'img-2' },
 { img : 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', alt : 'alternative text', clsas:'img-3' }];
 
 var htmlOutput = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  for(var i = 0; i < imgObj.length; i++)
  {
      var imageElement = '<img src="#SRC#" alt="#ALT#" class="#CLASS#" />';
      htmlOutput += imageElement.replace('#SRC#', imgObj[i].img).replace('#ALT#', imgObj[i].alt).replace('#CLASS#',imgObj[i].class);
  }
  
  // Append the HTML string to the dom
  $('.img-container').append(htmlOutput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, If there is more than one picture? (I updated my question)

Comment: Thats good! But I think that this code need to read in sentences. For example: `Here are sample apartment pictures {img="/path/photo1.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"} and {img="/path/photo2.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title #2"}` - because it is not possible to make a listing because the data is taken from the database.

Comment: Doesn't matter, add random or ordered css class without getting it from the db, it is just for the example :)

Comment: If you want this screenshots: [DB](https://i.imgur.com/Tkr9pPr.jpg) - [Codes](https://i.imgur.com/gwximnc.jpg)  - [Print](https://i.imgur.com/iFtmkEC.png)  - [Source Print](https://i.imgur.com/fmaKZ2K.jpg)

Comment: As much as i can but I can do it because I have limited knowledge. Could you give me an idea of how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you select your `img` element, you can directly alter the `src` attribute. For example, for a given `img` element with id of "my-image":

```
<img id="my-image" src="/path/photo.jpg" alt="I am Photo Title"/>
```

You can select the image via `document.getElementById`:

```
var img = document.getElementById('my-image');
```

Then edit the `src` attribute directly on the `img` element:

```
img.src = '/my-new-img-path.jpg`
```

Here's an example for updating multiple images, that all have a class of `"edit-image"`:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-image');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].src = '/my-new-img-path.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, If there is more than one picture? (I updated my question)

Comment: updated for iterating thru multiple images selected via `getElementsByClassName()`